# A version of Tanaka equation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Does the following equation has a well known weak solution:
$$dX_t = \rm{sgn}(X_t)dB^1_t + dB^2_t$$
for independent $B^1$ and $B^2?$ If so does it have unique distribution? The original Tanaka equation can be solved with a simple trick but in this case I could not find any way to get my head around it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is studied in the article ["THE SOLUTION OF THE PERTURBED TANAKA-EQUATION IS PATHWISE UNIQUE"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.0740.pdf)

[image]